mypy variable type hints - are they assertions or declarations?
I'm very confused what variable type hints in python (using mypy) actually do. My understanding is that they are useful for asserting the right hand side of assignment actually has the same type as the type hint on the left hand side. But it looks like there is some declaration component as well.
I am looking at this function. When I run mypy, I get the following error:
def get_organization_from_query_params(query_params: QueryDict) -> Organization:
    organization_id = query_params.get("organization_id")
    organization = get_object_or_404(Organization.objects.active(), pk=organization_id)
    return organization

mypy --strict --follow-imports=silent reports: error: Returning Any from function declared to return "Organization"  [no-any-return]
However, when I add type hints to organization by changing the line into organization: Organization = get_object_or_404(Organization.objects.active(), pk=organization_id), mypy is super happy with no problem.
In this case, does mypy just automatically assume that from this point going forward organization is of type Organization? How can it assume that's correct if previously mypy thought get_object_or_404 returns an object of type Any, but I didn't change the functionality at all, and now it believes the fact that get_object_or_404 returns an object of type Organization? Does writing a type hint trigger BOTH an assertion and a declaration??

Any basically means "don't type check this",  and yes, it basically means "accept anything here", so you annoate organization: Organization, assign Any to it, and since it is Any that is acceptable. This is the problem with Any. It's meant to be an "escape valve" from type annotations. So try doing something like organization: Organization = [1, 2, 3] to see the difference.

"How can it assume that's correct if previously mypy thought get_object_or_404 returns an object of type Any," because that's the whole point of Any. The problem here is that get_object_or_404 returns Any. that should be fixed.

I don't know what you mean by "assertions". They are not assertions in the normal programming sense (e.g., like using assert), but in a sense, I can see what you mean by calling them "assertions".

Type hints are by default not enforced.

If you read Pep 483 (and I would recommend doing so), you'll see that the is-consistent-with relation (which is what uses Any) doesn't apply to function return values, only assignments.

Since the example you show looks painfully familiar, you may want to install and configure django-stubs - typechecking Django without those stubs and plugin wil be, uhm, painful. get_object_or_404 is well-typed and get_object_or_404(Organization.objects.active(), pk=pk) will produce the correct type.

Errors with code no-any-return (generated by --warn-return-any  which is included in --strict) are somewhat pedantic. I fairly frequently disable this configuration option.
The idea is that in your original code, due to Any you may have a value of the wrong type returned (which can then wreak havoc elsewhere in your program). In your original code, there's no way for you to tell that this is the case! The code would be unchanged if get_object_or_404 returned a statically known type instead of Any.
By adding an explicit variable annotation (or even better, an assert), mypy forces the developer (or with an assert, the runtime) to confirm that the types are correct.
To answer more narrowly, variable annotations are declarations. If mypy can see a way to make the types line up with the declarations, it will (with the benefit of doubt being given to gradual forms like Any). Use of assert and cast (and TypeIs / TypeGuard / overload) are more assertions, in that they tell mypy things mypy wouldn't otherwise assume.
